# Why is there not control panel in the task bar?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, windows, vidalia

tor is never in the task bar and i would like to see the control panel, i download tor several times and mozilla to.. i don't understand. Can you help me please ? I didn't find the answer anywhere.

( I'm French so sorry for the faults)

Comment: Please don't post duplicate questions (especially if you're aware of the fact that it's a duplicate); the question you linked to was already a duplicate and clearly states where to find the original question / answer. Thanks!